# jQuery not loading at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, onload

I'm trying out jQuery for the first time, and I'm not sure how to make it work properly. I've included the following code near my opening `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Followed by the following jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $('.darkmask > img').hover(function(){
             $(this).parent().toggleClass('darkmask-hover');
    })​
</script>
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work when I try it in a browser, or in JSFiddle. However, [when I set JSFiddle's framework to load jQuery itself](http://jsfiddle.net/Verandaguy/AAXSX/6/), rather than loading jQuery through my own code, the animation works properly.

Am I loading jQuery wrong? If so, what's the right way?

Comment: which navigator are you using ?

Comment: I've tested it in Safari 6.0, Firefox 14.0, Chrome 21.0, and Opera 12.0, all on Mac OS (the full page has all the vendor prefixes).

Comment: I think the problem is not in your code. When you go to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js have you got the js ?

Comment: Of course. That's where Google hosts their low-latency jQuery file.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/AAXSX/10/

Comment: What isn't working on my end, is that for some reason, it seems that the jQuery file doesn't actually initialize.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15466/discussion-between-charles-jourdan-and-verandaguy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PRoblem is, your code in JSFiddle is executed on the loading on the page. In your code instead, the execution happens when the HTML elements are **not yet** loaded because it's in the `HEAD`, so the selectors like `.darkmask` actually refer to... nothing.

The solution is to use:

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
 ... your code here
}
```

To ensure that it is executed when the page is loaded and ready, all the HTML elements are there and therefore JQuery selectors can operate on something.

Comment: [I've updated the code](http://jsfiddle.net/Verandaguy/AAXSX/7/). It still doesn't seem to work.
For the record, do I wrap my entire document in the code you provided, or just the jQuery code (I did the latter)?

Comment: I've tried it again in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Verandaguy/AAXSX/9/), and it actually seems to work; but when I try it in-browser, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in:

```
$(function() {
    .... Your code here ...

});
```

It will mean your code is executed after the DOM tree is loaded.

Comment: Actually $(function(){... means jQuery is loaded and the DOM tree has been created.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa I'm aware of this as it's an alias of `$(document).ready` but it is still the correct solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Are there any HTML elements when the code is executed?

Try:

```
$(function () { // this function executes when the page loads
   alert(x);
   // put your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your entire code in the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //ALL CODE GOES HERE

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to wrap your jQuery code within the ready function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // put your code here.
});
```

Also make sure your script tags have type="text/javascript" as an attribute otherwise it won't get run as javascript.